# ABP Framework - To which layer belongs background worker

Tags: background-process, abp

I searched the documentation without finding a clear answer to this question.
I want to create a background worker in ABP Framework (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Workers).

But I don't know in which project / layer I should create it. I have the feeling the background job belongs to Domain layer. Is it correct? Does it belongs to the Application layer instead? Or does it depends of what the background worker does?
What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, I think it depends on what the background worker does. But generally speaking, I think it should be in the domain layer because it's not a use-case that can be triggered with user/actor interaction, it is just a worker service that runs periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better not to put background work into domain layer, it's not a domain logic, but more about user-case.

We'd better put it into presentation layer.

In abp docs, it did not says it directly, but we can find some evidence about it.（Reference: [https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Workers-Hangfire#configuration）](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Workers-Hangfire#configuration%EF%BC%89)

As it says:

> we change the Module class (example: `<YourProjectName>HttpApiHostModule`) to add Hangfire configuration of the storage and connection string in the `ConfigureServices` method

So abp gives a example that register background worker in `HttpApiHostModule`, and `HttpApiHostModule` is in presentation layer which is higher than application layer.